# Why is foam coming out of the kitchen drain while washing dishes?

Tags: kitchens, drain

I am in Saudi Arabia using FAIRY liquid dish washer to clean my dishes after meals. Every time I observe that the foam is coming out of the drainage located at the kitchen floor during my cleaning of the dirty dishes with FAIRY lemon liquid dish washer.

What is the problem? Why does this foam (bubble while color) come out every time I wash my dirty dishes? What should I do to get rid of this?

Comment: Are you **sure** you're using the right type of soap? Most automatic dishwasher machine soap does not foam - you cannot use the same sort of dishwashing liquid you use for hand-washing dishes (even if it happens to be the same brand.) The only time I've seen signficant foam from an automatic dishwasher is when hand-type dishwashing soap was put in by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by making sure you aren't just using too much soap in the dishwasher. More likely, the dishwasher is pumping water into the same waste pipe that the floor drain is connected to, and the pipe can't handle the water fast enough to keep the floor drain from backing up. I'd suggest two things:

First, check to make sure that the drain itself isn't running slow and start treating it with an [enzyme drain cleaner](https://www.google.com/#q=enzyme+drain+cleaner&tbm=shop). It probably wouldn't hurt to run a plumbing snake down the drain to make sure it isn't partially blocked.

Second, you can install a [floor drain check valve](https://www.google.com/#q=floor+drain+check+valve&tbm=shop) for the drain in the kitchen floor to keep water from backing up through it. Even if you can resolve the issue by cleaning out the drain, this would probably be a good idea. You never know what *else* might back up through there some day.

Comment: Definitely some great advise
!